# pycharm error highlighting

Tags: pycharm

I am using pycharm, and, sometimes, the editor thinks i have a mistake in my coding.

Maybe it thinks that a variable is poorly declared, or doesn't exist, or a bracket isn't in the right place?

Naturally, the editor is wrong and my coding is perfect. Still, to raise bugs to the pycharm team, i need to be able to clearly see where these "errors" are.

Currently, the editor tends to employ "nearly invisible grey" as the color scheme of choice for "errors".

What are the steps i need to take to change the color scheme to something more noticable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `General`:

[image: colors & fonts]

Comment: i just wish i could give more points for this. this is an exceptional answer, thanks for going the extra mile with the image!