# PyCharm does not highlight errors

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with PyCharm v2.7.
it does not show me errors.
I have configured it to show them as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703984/pycharm-error-highlighting)
but nothing.
here a screenshot of what I see (no error displayed)
[image]

if I run code analysis it shows the errors marked as INVALID in the window but it does not highlight the code.
any idea?

Comment: I found. i've enabled by chance the "power safe mode" that avoid error checking.
it can be re-enabled by clicking on the little man on bottom right corner.

Comment: This was bugging me a couple of days ago, found it out by myself. Wish this thread was here before though, wasted a lot of time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found. i've enabled by chance the "power safe mode" that avoid error checking. it can be re-enabled by clicking on the little man on bottom right corner.

Comment: There is no little man in the bottom right corner. How else can it be done?

Comment: check in the actions/settings if you have power safe mode enabled

Comment: Is that little man with us in this room right now? Can't find that power safe mode anywhere.

Answer (score 63):

I had this issue recently on PyCharm 2020.3.3 Community Edition.

What I've found is in the top right corner of the editor there is a `Reader Mode` button.
If you click it you turn the Reader Mode off and then you can see your errors.

[image]

You can re-enable it by clicking the book icon
[image: Enter Reader Mode]

Comment: Does anyone know how this gets turned on by accident? I do not see a hotkey for it.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I think it gets turned on by upgrading PyCharm - it's on by default in the newer version.

Comment: I noticed that whenever I create a new project, Reader Mode is on by default. I would assume that is irregular, perhaps there is some setting I accidentally turned on to enable this behavior.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had some ticks disabled in the Python Inspections menu in `Settings > Editor > Inspections > Python`. I have ticked everything and applied, and now it is working.

[image: Settings > Editor > Inspections > Python]

I don't really understand why this happened as the problem arose from one day to another. I had even re-installed the whole PyCharm, trying older versions, and deleted the *.pycharm* configuration folder from *home*.

Answer (score 3):

None of the previous answers worked for me when I ran into this issue, but I was able to fix it by doing a hard reset on my PyCharm settings:

From the main menu, select <kbd>File</kbd> | <kbd>Manage IDE Settings</kbd> | <kbd>Restore Default Settings</kbd>.

You will lose all your custom settings this way of course, but this was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with PyCharm Community Edition, v.2016.3.2. To fix, 
go to `Preferences...` from the PyCharm menu, and open `Editor/Colors & Fonts/General`

Now go to  `Errors and Warnings/Error` under your current schema.

I also had to set my `Project Interpreter` under `Preferences/Project:<name>/Project Interpreter`.

See screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many things, but only `Invalidate Caches` did the trick, after that I could hover the green arrow (top right side) and change `Highlight` to `All Problems`[image]

Comment: Oh my god, thank you! I tried everything, default settings, updates, etc. Reinstall. But only this worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of this worked for me.

My problem was a single warning: "unreachable code" which blocked all errors from being highlighted.

I removed this line of code (+ the warning) and all errors showed up again.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. It was only one file; error detection in every other file in every other project worked. I commented out the unreachable code and all the error checking was reenabled.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by clicking the lock (read-only mode) in the lower right on and off

Comment: it works! i have cleaned cache several times and it did not help for this case, but should. (pycharm 2022.3)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to "Add content root" under "Project Structure" in Preferences. I had no content root.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was a symptom of having created the file in the wrong place without realising. Before taking any drastic actions, check your project structure